# different fonts in tkinter canvas text items

Tags: python, text, tkinter, fonts, widget

Is there any approach to have certain words with certain fond in "canvas items"? Like `tag_configure` and `tag_add` for "text widget"?

```
x = canvas.create_text(10, 10, text = "$-3", font = "calibri 30")
```

I need `$` a font, and `-3` a font.

I have tried to create `Text()` in `master`, but the text is blocked by the canvas items.

Comment: I think you will have to create one canvas item per font or to embed a `Text` widget in your canvas using `create_window`.

Comment: @j_4321 do you mean create `$` and `-3` separately?

Comment: Yes, because I don't think you can use two different fonts in the same canvas item.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to use two different fonts in the same canvas item, but what you can do is to create two items like that:

```
canvas.create_text(10, 10, text='$', font='calibri 30', anchor='e')
canvas.create_text(10, 10, text='-3', font='Arial 20', anchor='w')
```

I used `anchor='e'` on the left piece of text and `anchor='w'` on the right one in order to position them next to one another as if it was a single item.